# Query to list all invoices for customers with more than one

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's a simplified version of the two tables:

```
Invoice
========
InvoiceID
CustomerID
InvoiceDate
TransactionDate
InvoiceTotal

Customer
=========
CustomerID
CustomerName
```

What I want is a listing of all invoices where there is more than one per customer. I don't want to group or count the invoices, I actually need to see all invoices. The output would look something like this:

```
CustomerName    TransactionDate    InvoiceTotal
-------------------------------------------------
Ted Tester      2012-12-14         335.49
Ted Tester      2013-02-02         602.00
Bob Beta        2013-05-04         779.50
Bob Beta        2013-07-07          69.00
Bob Beta        2013-09-10         849.79
```

What's the best way to write a query for SQL Server to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
SELECT  C.CustomerName,
        I.TransactionDate,
        I.InvoiceTotal
FROM dbo.Invoice I
INNER JOIN dbo.Customer C
    ON I.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Invoice
             WHERE CustomerID = I.CustomerID
             GROUP BY CustomerID
             HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

And another way for SQL Server 2005+:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  C.CustomerName,
            I.TransactionDate,
            I.InvoiceTotal,
            N = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY I.CustomerID)
    FROM dbo.Invoice I
    INNER JOIN dbo.Customer C
        ON I.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE N > 1
```

Comment: Your EXISTS probably performs better than my NOT IN solution.  I would be interested in the analysis of that.

Comment: What if I wanted to limit this by date? TransactionDate >= 2013-01-01

Comment: @planeBrad Then you first need to specify if you want only duplicates that were on that date or if you just want to filter the current results for that date (those are different requirements)

Comment: I think I figured out my own question. I just added the TransactionDate parameter to the WHERE statement.

Answer (score 2):

Using a window function will make this very clean to do - this will be supported by SQL Server 2005 and greater:

```
SELECT CustomerName, TransactionDate, InvoiceTotal
FROM (
  SELECT c.CustomerName, i.TransactionDate, i.InvoiceTotal, 
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY i.CustomerId) as InvoiceCount
  FROM Invoice i
  JOIN Customer c ON i.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
) t
WHERE InvoiceCount > 1
```

Comment: Interesting -- using PARTITION BY to get around having to do a GROUP BY.  I like it.

Answer (score 0):

Good old GROUP BY HAVING in a subselect using IN clause:

```
SELECT c2.CustomerName, i2.TransactionDate, i2.InvoiceTotal
FROM Invoice i2
    INNER JOIN Customer c2 ON i2.CustomerID = c2.CustomerID
WHERE i2.CustomerID IN (
    SELECT c.CustomerID
    FROM Customer c
        INNER JOIN Invoice i on i.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    GROUP BY c.CustomerID
    HAVING COUNT(i.InvoiceID) > 1
)
```